# Setter injection on Interface is taking only the exact name from configurations else throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am learning Spring and was trying to implement the following code from the book "Spring in Action". I am not able to understand as to why the Interface property declared with exact name works and else doesn't for a simple Spring application(3.0). Please look into this:

```
public interface Instrument {
 public void play();
}

public interface Performer 
{
 void perform();
}
public class Saxophone implements Instrument 
{
 public void play() {
    System.out.println("TOOT TOOT TOOT");
 }
}
public class Instrumentalist implements Performer
{

 private String song;
 private Instrument obj; *// not working
 // private Instrument instrument; This will work, if replaced* accordingly in the code

 public void setSong(String song)
 {
    this.song=song;
 }
 public void setInstrument(Instrument instrumen)
 {
    obj=instrumen;
 }
 public Instrument getInstrument()
 {
    return obj;
 }
 public String getSong()
 {
    return song;
 }
 public void perform(){
    System.out.println("Playing "+song+" : ");
    obj.play();
 }
}
```

The Main class is :

```
import org.springframework.context.*;
import org.springframework.context.support.*;
class Main
{
 public static void main(String ar[])
 {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("abc.xml");
    Performer performer = (Performer) ctx.getBean("kenny");
    performer.perform();
 }
}
```

And the configuration are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
default-init-method="turnONLights" default-destroy-method="turnOFFLights">

 <bean id="kenny" class="Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="Jingle Bells" />
    <property name="obj" ref="saxophone" />
    <!-- here also I need to replace obj with "instrument" to make it work -->
 </bean>
 <bean id="saxophone" class="Saxophone"/>

</beans>
```

This might be a basic question but yet I am not able to get it.Please help me understand that is it necessary to have the Interface variable have the same name?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part looks incorrect...

```
<property name="obj" ref="saxophone" />
```

The value of the `name` attribute needs to be derived from the setter method;  in this case, it looks like you want...

```
<property name="instrument" ref="saxophone" />
```

Notice that the characters s-e-t are removed, and the first character -- 'i' -- is lower case.

Comment: Thanks. It worked and moreover I understood. This was actually a silly question and I should have got it myself. My Bad :(